# Query related to GGA+U calculation in SIESTA

Tags: siesta, dft-u

I want to calculate the electronic band structure for CuWO4 using the GGA+U method. Is it necessary to optimize the structure using the same GGA+U method or only we can incorporate GGA+U parameter in the bandstructure calculation? Actually, I don't have any idea regarding the GGA+U calculation so could you please help me in this regard?
Thanking you
with regards
Jyotirmoy

Comment: Related older post: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/8581/do-the-u-values-affect-structure-optimization-with-the-dftu-simulation-to-optim

Answer (score 4):

I'm not entirely sure why you're asking the question, but I'm going to assume that geometry optimisation with a GGA is straightforward, and it's the Hubbard U which you're concerned about - perhaps because it is harder to converge the SCF, or it takes more computational time.

Generally speaking, you should always optimise your system's geometry with the same exchange-correlation functional that you're using to compute its properties. However, it is often found that varying the Hubbard U term does not affect the forces very much in practice, so you *may* be able to optimise with the GGA only. If you do, you should definitely check that the forces for the GGA-optimised geometry are still small when you include the Hubbard U term.

See:

[Do the U values affect structure optimization with the DFT+U simulation to optimize crystal structure?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/8581/do-the-u-values-affect-structure-optimization-with-the-dftu-simulation-to-optim)

for a similar discussion (also linked by Tyberius).

I'm afraid I've never used SIESTA so I can't tell you anything about how to actually do the calculations with it. There is an online tutorial here:

https://docs.siesta-project.org/projects/siesta/tutorials/dft%2Bu/index.html